# Android ListView SectionIndexer with cursor

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create Category items based listview using SectionIndexer where data coming from ContentProvider. I have found some examples where they are setting data from cursor to HashMap or TreeMap. But its not a good way to use cursor. I wonder if there is a way to use cursor in sectionindexer without any collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AlphabetIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html) is what you need. It'll do all the work for you.

EDIT: For the CharSequence, use " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ". The " " at the beginning of the  char sequence is needed.

EDIT: [Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.java) the source code for AlphabetIndexer. Try customizing that to return the Section name instead of the alphabet.

Comment: I think this will arrange my listview in alphabetic order according to items name. Like in case of contact application. But I want to show my items not sorted by alphabet but sorted by category. Like Love Songs then Pop Songs then etc.

Comment: In Case of AlphabetIndexer header will show A, B, C order but I want header should show category name.

Comment: You'll probably have to write a custom class implementing Section Indexer then...